# Display final view after sign-out in DNX MVC 6 app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-core-mvc, dnx

I've read several examples discussing an issue I had recently with my first DNX 4.5 MVC 6 application, such as this: [Context.Response.SignOut no longer exists after ASP.NET vNext beta 6 upgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31679790/). The issue was that after calling `Context.Authentication.SignOutAsync` the user was immediately redirected to another page and the auth cookies were kept alive and so the user was never really logged out (or that's how I understand it, anyway).

The resolution seems to be to make the 'signout' method a void, and not return a view at all, which in fact works for me as well. This leads to a new issue, though: the user sees nothing since you never get to return anything. I am left at a completely blank 'page' after signing out. So what is the mechanism for sending them somewhere that's insecure after sign-out? if you're not returning anything i don't see how it can be done, but this can't be the way it's designed to work.

thanks.